# Angular Typescript: Assigning class members null or Union Type Operator Difference

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

Whats the difference between assigning things null, or giving Union type operator null. Either way, both data types allow class member to be null, so would like to understand. Is there a difference in behavior?

```
export class PropertyAddress {
    city?: string = null;
    state?: string = null;
    zipcode?: string = null;


export class PropertyAddress {
    city?: string | null;
    state?: string | null;
    zipcode?: string | null;
```

Background of question:

Wanted to declare a class, and ensure all members exist and start out as null, if Nothing is defined. Had an issue where class members were not appearing in debugger, if they were not preset –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a TypeScript thing.

The following line

```
city?: string = null;
```

means that you declared an attribute `city` of type `string` and **initialized** it with value `null`. In this case, if you set `--strictNullChecks` flag as `true` in its config then it will throw an error.

On the other hand, the following line

```
city?: string | null
```

means that you declared an attribute `city` of type `string` or `null` and you can make `city` value as `null` even with the `--strictNullChecks` flag set as `true`.

For More info - [check out TypeScript 2.0 release notes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html).

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html

Answer (score 1):

In fact,null is assignable to any type.If your property type is string,number or a class you can pass a null into them.But what is difference between these two property:

```
class test{
    city?: string | null;
    city2?: string = null;
}
```

If you make an instance of test class, the value of city would be undefined, but the value of city2 is null.

Comment: the value of city, would not show up in debugger either, for the first case

Comment: Yes, in debugger it would not show up.But in ts you have it.

Comment: In fact, without initialization you can not see them in debugger.

Answer (score 0):

1. `city?: string = null;`
   City's type here is string, and you initialised it as null.
2. `city?:string | null;`
   We use the vertical bar (|) to separate each type, **so here string | null is the type of city that can be a string or a null.** But **city** here has not been initialised.

Have a look of the Advanced Types with detailed explanation  URL: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

Hope it helps you.

Comment: so in the first, case it can be Both, And initialized,  in the second case, it can be Both, but Not initialized, is that correct? thanks

Comment: Hi, the first 'city?: string = null;' is initialised, but second 'city?:string | null;' is not initialised.